# Function get_queried_object() return NULL in custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Hi i need get term ID from custom taxonomy but it is always NULL.

`taxonomy-galerie-kategorie.php`

```
<?php
    /**
     * A custom taxonomy template for gallery.
     */
?>
<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/html-header', 'parts/shared/header' ) ); ?>

<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/templates/header-image' ) ); ?>

<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/templates/gallery' ) ); ?>

<?php Starkers_Utilities::get_template_parts( array( 'parts/shared/footer','parts/shared/html-footer' ) ); ?>
```

```
query_posts(['post_type' => 'galerie']);
    $terms = get_categories([
    'taxonomy' => 'galerie-kategorie',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
]);
var_dump(get_queried_object());
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You should never use `query_posts` to change the what gets shown on a page, I would purge all knowledge of that function as there are no valid uses of it in normal web development. Use the `pre_get_posts` filter to change what gets fetched from the database instead, and you'll avoid a lot of problems, and your site will be faster. For example you might not have noticed, but your pagination will be broken because you used `query_posts`

Comment: You had right! I used ```new WP_Query``` instead and everythink is fine :)

Comment: That fixes things a teeny bit, but it's nowhere near as simple/good as a `pre_get_posts` filter, you've gone from a 1/10 to a 3/10, `pre_get_posts` would be a 9/10 that uses half the code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any query at all, especially not `query_posts`.

Instead, use the `pre_get_posts` action to make sure that any query for that taxonomy for a frontend archive, has the appropriate post types:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) {
    // we only want the main query for galerie-kategorie archives
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || !$q->is_tax( 'galerie-kategorie' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $q->set( 'post_type', 'galerie' );
});
```

Now it will make sure WP grabs what you wanted the first time around.

Otherwise, by using a whole new `WP_Query`/`query_post` you:

- double the number of queries, WP did all that work and you've just thrown it in the trash and told it to do it all over again! Poor WP :(
- Make your page twice as slow as it has to do everything twice
- Breaks pagination! Now you have to do a tonne of extra work to get it working again, **and** you have to write custom pagination code to get the links working
- Introduces compatibility problems with plugins and code that use `pre_get_posts`
- Made your code longer
- Cluttered up your templates, a `pre_get_post` filter can be hidden away in `functions.php`

If you ever need to modify ro change the posts WP fetches from the database, use `pre_get_posts`. Think of it like changing your food order before you give it to kitchen. The last thing you want is to order food, have it arrive, then change your mind and have to wait again for new food.